# Qml FolderListModel fails to access shared folder

Tags: qt, qml

I have a program in Qt/Qml that uses a FolderListModel to list qml files in a folder

```
FolderListModel {
        id: progModel
        folder: "file:///" + application.dirPath()
       Component.onCompleted: console.log("folder: " + folder)
    }
```

This model is passed to a ListView

```
ListView{
    id: gridContent
    model: progModel
    delegate: progDelegate
}
```

It works well when the application runs in the Windows host, however if I share the application folder and try to run it from other Windows OS then the application fails to detect the folder.

Now we are using the Qt 5.9.3 and  QtQuick 2.3. Before it worked well, when it was used Qt 5.5 and QtQuick 1.0

Note: If I put the URL showed from the console.log, something like "file://my_remote_path" the Windows Explorer open the folder correctly.

I have written a small piece of code to make the problem more clear

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1
ApplicationWindow {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 600
title: qsTr("Hello World")
SwipeView {
    id: swipeView
    anchors.fill: parent
    Page {
        Rectangle{
            id: rect1
            color: "#cccccc"
            anchors{top: parent.top; horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter}
            width: parent.width * 0.6
            height: parent.height*0.9

            FolderListModel{
                id: progfolder
                showDirs: true
                showDirsFirst: true
                folder: "file://quatro/visao/qml/reportDialog"                        // It does not work
                //folder: "file:///programming/comm5-qt5.6/visao/test/qml/reportDialog" // It works
                //folder: "file:///programming/comm5-qt5.6/visao/reportDialog.lnk"        // It works
                nameFilters: ["*.qml"]
                Component.onCompleted: console.log("folder " + folder)
            }

            ListView{
                id: lv
                anchors.fill: parent
                model: progfolder
                delegate: progDelegate
            }

            Component{
                id: progDelegate

                Text{
                    text: fileName
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

This time I run the program say in PC2 but set the folder property to a shared folder in PC1, say "file://quatro/visao/qml/reportDialog". The problem is the same.

I have also comment two other ways to set the folder property. If I choose a local folder there is no problem. If I use a link to the share folder it also works but if I try to set the remote path it does not work.

Comment: eyllanesc  - I think it is ok  with the dll's. If a run this program directly from the host it runs well. It is also no error logs about dll's as normally happens when something is not found.

Comment: Okay, what do you mean by shared folder?

Comment: Did you `import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1` ?

Comment: Shared folder is using windows file sharing feature in network group.

Comment: eyllanesc - I have a PC1 and PC2. In PC1 I have shared the folder c:\folder1 to be read from all my network, using properties->share-advanced-share. Then the folder1 may be open from PC2, however if I run my program located in c:\folder1 from the PC2 then the FolderListModel does not show the inner folder as normally happened.

Comment: Once I saw a similar question and what is concluded is that Qt does not support that feature, it would be interesting that it does so at present.

Comment: Mohammad Kanan - Yes I did import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1

Comment: Same problem, any workaround?